# Creating random integers with distribution schema

Tags: probability-distributions

I need to create an array that includes 0..5 integers. I'm able to create them randomly. But I need to create them according to below distributions.
How can I get below distributions?
[image: Distribution]

Ps: I'm using numpy to create the array.